# How to transform a curve in a specific way

Tags: matlab, curve, spline

I have the following curve (example data that's somewhat sparse, but should get the point across). There are four points along this curve (indicated by the arrows), that I'd like to use as reference points. These points need to be shifted by specified amounts (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4` respectively) in the direction the arrow species. It will always be these four locations that need to be shifted by specific amounts. **However, it's not as easy as shifting those specific points, because I need to maintain the overall shape of the curve.**

There are constraints that will always be maintained. The arrow associated with `x2` will never overlap with the arrow specified by x1. The arrow associated with `x3` will never surpass that of `x2`. The arrow associated with `x4` will never surpass that associated with `x3`. The curve will always have this general shape and will always be shifted at these 4 points.

In other words, the arrows in the image below are representative examples of the way that this curve should be shifted.

[image]

How can I do this? One idea I had was to fit some sort of spline and then somehow transform that spline in an elegant way based on these points. But I'm really not sure.

Here is the data from this example in Matlab

```
x = [6; 7; 7.2; 7.3; 7.5; 7.7; 7.9; 8; 8.13; 8.2; 8.21; 8.31; 8.4; 8.41; 8.45; 8.47; 8.5; 8.6; 8.8; 9; 9.6; 10];
y = [0; 0.01; 0.02; 0.1; 1; 1.1; 0.9; 0.6; 0; -0.5; -1; -1.1; -0.93; -0.9; -0.7; -0.6; -0.2; 0; 0.1; 0.12; 0; 0];
plot(x,y);
```

**Example of end-goal**
You can see how the entire curve has shifted by the specified amounts but the whole shape is maintained.
[image]

Comment: How did you generate this curve in the first place? Specifically, how did you define the shape within each interval (x1,x2), (x2, x3) and (x3, x4)?

Comment: It's experimental data, not generated from a model...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to stretch the parts individually by moving the four points. Therefore it is a simple operation of adjusting all the points within the bounds. The **overall shape of the curve is maintained** as long as your constraint of non-overlapping is fulfilled.

Of course it is not as easy as shifting *only the points*. But you can do the following for *each part* of the curve.

1. Shift to zero.
2. Stretch with calculated factor.
3. Shift back to where the part has to be in the *final* curve.

**Here is an implementation** doing exactly this. The indexes of the «moving points» are specified in `ind` and the amount to be moved in respect to the x-axis is specified in `val`.

```
x   = [6; 7; 7.2; 7.3; 7.5; 7.7; 7.9; 8; 8.13; 8.2; 8.21; 8.31; 8.4; 8.41; 8.45; 8.47; 8.5; 8.6; 8.8; 9; 9.6; 10];
y   = [0; 0.01; 0.02; 0.1; 1; 1.1; 0.9; 0.6; 0; -0.5; -1; -1.1; -0.93; -0.9; -0.7; -0.6; -0.2; 0; 0.1; 0.12; 0; 0];
ind = [  3;    6;    12;    21];        % The indexes of points to be moved
val = [0.1; -0.1;  -0.2;  -0.8];        % Value/amount of movement

% Extend scope to beginning and end of data
i = [1,ind',length(x)];                 % All the bounds
v = [0;val;0];                          % Movements of all bounds

% Split original curve in parts and store them in a cell array
orig = cell(1,length(i)-1);             % preallocation
for n = 1:(length(i)-1)
    orig{n} = [x(i(n):i(n+1)),y(i(n):i(n+1))];
end

% Stretch the parts and move them to the correct position
new = cell(size(orig));                 % preallocation
for n = 1:length(orig)
    a = orig{n}(1,1);                   % first x value
    b = orig{n}(end,1);                 % last x value
    p = (b-a+v(n+1)-v(n))/(b-a);        % factor to stretch
    xn = ((orig{n}(:,1)-a)*p)+a+v(n);   % calculate new x positions
    new{n} = [xn,orig{n}(:,2)];         % add result to cell-array
end

% Put the parts together
% Simple concenation creates double entries at moving points,
% therefore the first part is added outside the loop.
% Preallocation is omitted on purpose.
xn = new{1}(:,1);
yn = new{1}(:,2);
for n = 2:length(new)
    xn = [xn;new{n}(2:end,1)]; %#ok<AGROW>
    yn = [yn;new{n}(2:end,2)]; %#ok<AGROW>
end

% Display data
figure; hold on;
plot(x(ind),y(ind),'ro');               % Plot original points
plot(x,y,'b.-');                        % Plot original curve
plot(x(ind)+val,y(ind),'go');           % Plot new points
plot(xn,yn,'k.-');                      % Plot new curve
legend('Original points','Original curve','New points','New curve');

% Plot the new parts separately
%hold all;
%for n = 1:length(new)
%    nc = plot(new{n}(:,1),new{n}(:,2));
%end
```

*This will give you the following result:*
[image: Example result of given code.]

**On request:** For a better understanding what happens, the following code is a simplified version, only shifting the last point by the given amount of `value`.

```
x = [6; 7; 7.2; 7.3; 7.5; 7.7; 7.9; 8; 8.13; 8.2; 8.21; 8.31; 8.4; 8.41; 8.45; 8.47; 8.5; 8.6; 8.8; 9; 9.6; 10];
y = [0; 0.01; 0.02; 0.1; 1; 1.1; 0.9; 0.6; 0; -0.5; -1; -1.1; -0.93; -0.9; -0.7; -0.6; -0.2; 0; 0.1; 0.12; 0; 0];

value = -1;             % the last point will be shifted by this value

p = (x(end)-x(1)+value)/(x(end)-x(1));

% Override of p
%p = 2.0;               % p=2.0 will double the length
%p = 0.5;               % p=0.5 will halve the length

x2 = ((x-x(1)) * p) + x(1);

figure; hold on;
plot(x,y,'*-');
plot(x2,y,'ro-');
```

*This will give you the following result:*
[image: Result of simplified version.]

Comment: Thank you so much. What do you mean by shifting each part to zero?

Comment: `(orig{n}(:,1)-a)` shifts the part `n` to zero. A multiplication by `p` is not giving an additional shift then. After the multiplication it shifts the result back with `a+v(n)`. Without the shifting it would result in a distorted curve.

Comment: Sorry, still trying to understand this. Can you explain how you're calculating the stretch factor p.

Comment: We have points `[2 4 6]`. We want to shift the 6 by `v=-2` but preserving the 'shape'. The result is `[2 3 4]` when 2 is a fixed point. To do this we can shift [2 4 6] to the origin by subtracting the first value (2). -> `[0 2 4]`. Then we need to know the stretch-factor `p`. `p` is the relative difference of the length after/before -> `(6-2-v)/(6-2)=2/4=0.5=p`. Now we calculate `[0 2 4]*p=[0 1 2]`. Now we need to shift back to the fixed point (2). -> `[0 1 2]+2=[2 3 4]`. If there are more parts, then `p` needs to take both bounds `a` and `b` and both shifts `v(n+1)` and `v(n)` into account.

Comment: Could you actually do me a favor and post code that just shifts like one portion just so I can try and understand what's happening? For example, code that only shifts the 2nd reference point by x2.

Comment: @CodeGuy: I added a simplified version to the post. I did not take the second point but the last one as the moving reference, so the whole curve gets shifted/moved. The principle behind can be seen clearly. I hope it helps, otherwise just ask me.

Comment: A few comments above, you say we have points [2,4,6]. Do you mean x-values or y-values? A point has an x and y value. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeGuy: These are `x`-values, since they get moved. The `y`-values stay the same and do not change.

Comment: Matt, wondering if you could add code to also scale the y-values based on reference y-value shifts?

Comment: @CodeGuy: You can change `a = orig{n}(1,1)` to `a = orig{n}(1,2)` and `b = orig{n}(end,1);` to `b = orig{n}(end,2);` and `xn = ((orig{n}(:,1)-a)*p)+a+v(n);` to `yn = ((orig{n}(:,2)-a)*p)+a+v(n);` and `new{n} = [xn,orig{n}(:,2)];` to `new{n} = [orig{n}(:,1),yn];`.